# How to remove unwanted characters in tcl variable value?

Tags: variables, tcl

I have extracted a full name and stored it into a variable.

The below is just for illustrative purpose. In reality,the variable $a is extracted from a log file.

like

```
set a "John Doe"
```

The issue is that I can't figure out if there any special characters in the full name which is extracted. I basically tried everything.

Using trimleft,trimright or trim for trailing whitespace. This didn't resolve the issue.
Also tried printing ASCII code values, but could only find the same codes as represented in the full name.

I needed some help with ideas or suggestions about how we can go ahead and remove any unwanted characters in the full name.
The only thing which is bugging me I don't know what those unwanted characters are.

Comment: What's a "special character"? What problem are you having?

Comment: I will remove tags. But the special character could be anything. I am not able to figure out yet. I thought initially whitespace, or /t at the starting and end. But that didn't help much.

Comment: What are "non-special" characters? Is there a specific set of characters that are allowed?

Comment: Non special characters can be anything like extra space, or tabs. I thought it had something to do with encoding of the Full name which is fetched from the logs.set fullName [encoding convertto utf-8 $a]

This didn't help.On display in console, i only see the Full name "John Doe" . I dont find anything unusual.
I am having hard time figuring out what or which characters is causing this issue. This name which is fetched from our tcl variable,
is further  used in a SQL query to fetch some records from DB. But we are not getting any hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an *exact* definition of what is a “special character”, it is extremely difficult to suggest anything concrete. However, if we assume that we're talking about converting all sequences of non-alphanumeric characters to something defined (such as `_`) then we can use `regsub` to do the task:

```
set b [regsub -all {\W+} $a "_"]
```

In your case, it turns `John Doe` into `John_Doe`. It also turns `**{!John . . . %%''   '''(Doe)@@` into `_John_Doe_`.

---

The regular expression `\W+` matches (maximally) any non-empty sequence of non-word (non-alphanumeric) characters. That's pretty good for cleaning up a very large fraction of weird user inputs. (It's imperfect for names though, as `Patrick O'Brien` will tell you. Names are plain old tricky.)